# Querying complex html document

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to query a complex web app for some data...

A very simplified example is the below

```
<section class="Test newTest testTest active">
  <div>
   </div>
   <a class="classLink1 classlink2 classlink3" data-render="test">Link</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="Test newTest testTest">
  <div>
   </div>
   <a class="classLink1 classlink2 classlink3" data-render="test">Link</a>
   </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Problem

- There are a few `<a>` tags with very similasr class names and some dataset with unique values which I don't want to query
- I'm trying to only target the `<a>` tag where the parent `<section>` has an `.active` class. But it may not be the immediate parent if that makes sense

I am trying something like this

```
document.querySelectorAll('section.Test.newTest.testTest.active a.classLink1.classlink2.classlink3 [data-render="test"]')
```

But it seems to return an empty nodelist.

Comment: `a.classLink1 classlink2 classlink3 [data-render="test"]` -> `a.classLink1.classlink2.classlink3[data-render="test"]`

Comment: read what a "space" does in [css selectors documentaion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators)

Answer (score 0):

You must not have the space between `classlink3` and `[data-render="test"]`, as the elements you are searching for have both classes and attribute, and aren't nested inside the "classes" element.

The right selector should be

`'section.Test.newTest.testTest.active a.classLink1.classlink2.classlink3[data-render="test"]'`

Which will select the following

[image]

Instead of

[image]

Comment: What I do to avoid such "typos" when answering such basic questions (and one line of javascript is as basic as you get) is to provide the answer in the form of a runnable snippet - that way, you know the code works :p